# Рисование сложных линии(border?)

Tags: html, css

Как нарисовать **адаптивные линии с точками,** которые на картинке снизу.
Я бы мог скинуть пример моего кода, но я понятия не имею **как рисовать такие сложные линии** =([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 6em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue blue transparent transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вариант с точками:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px dotted silver;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 6em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: calc(1em - 1px);
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 1em 1em, red .5em, transparent calc(.5em + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 1em) calc(100% - 1em), red .5em, transparent calc(.5em + 1px));
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid;
  z-index: -1;
}

div::before {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  border-color: transparent transparent blue blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
}

div::after {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-color: blue blue transparent transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Хлебушек, кладём внутрь div и через position: absolute. Ну или вообще добавить этой штуке padding и сделать через radial-gradient.

Comment: А как cделать точки на обоих концах?

Comment: Как нарисовать центральную и левую линию?

Comment: @Хлебушек, добавил точки.

Comment: Вот это чудо, как вам отдать последние 100 рейтинга?

Comment: Если вам не составит труда, то покажите пожалуйста центральную и правую линию =)

Comment: Что значит   grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr ? палочка "/" по середине что это? Тут 4 ряда или 2?

Comment: @Хлебушек, `первая-строка вторая-строка / первая-колонка вторая-колонка`. В инспекторе посмотри - он же показывает сетку.

Comment: А зачем ставить палочку "/" ? Что она дает?

Comment: @Хлебушек, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Comment: Каким образом нарисовать центральную линию?
Уже третий день ломаю голову =(

Answer (score 1):

Все три линии адаптивные, к тому же есть параметры завязанные не [CSS переменных](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).
Но если количество блоков и\или вид линий будет изменятся - то придётся всё переделывать.

```css
/* Основные стили блок */
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  
  --line-weight: 2px;
  --line-color: #999;
  --line-radius: 10px;
  --line-dot-size: 16px;
}

.item {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.item:nth-child(1) {--accent-color: #18adb4;}
.item:nth-child(2) {--accent-color: #1685a3; margin: 0 20px;}
.item:nth-child(3) {--accent-color: #275469;}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

/* когда .card будет заполняться, правило ниже нужно будет убрать. */
.card::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50%;
}

.line-block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  border: 0 solid var(--line-color);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: calc(var(--line-dot-size) / 2);
}

.line::before,
.item:nth-child(2) .line::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--line-dot-size);
  height: var(--line-dot-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.item:nth-child(1) .line,
.item:nth-child(3) .line {
  height: calc(50% - (var(--line-weight) / 2 + var(--line-dot-size) / 2));
}

/* LINE 1 */
.item:nth-child(1) .line:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 var(--line-radius);
  border-left-width: var(--line-weight);
  border-bottom-width: var(--line-weight);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: calc(var(--line-weight) * -.5);
}

.item:nth-child(1) .line:nth-child(1)::before {
  margin-left: calc(var(--line-weight) * -.5);
}

.item:nth-child(1) .line:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 0 var(--line-radius) 0 0;
  border-right-width: var(--line-weight);
  border-top-width: var(--line-weight);
  top: calc(50% - (var(--line-weight) / 2 + var(--line-dot-size) / 2));
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: calc(var(--line-weight) * -.5);
}

.item:nth-child(1) .line:nth-child(2)::before {
  left: calc(100% + var(--line-weight) / 2);
  top: 100%;
}

/* LINE 2 */
.item:nth-child(2) .line {
  width: var(--line-weight);
  height: calc(100% - var(--line-dot-size));
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: var(--line-color);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.item:nth-child(2) .line::before,
.item:nth-child(2) .line::after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: var(--line-weight * -.5);
}

.item:nth-child(2) .line::after {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* LINE 3 */
.item:nth-child(3) .line:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--line-radius) 0;
  border-right-width: var(--line-weight);
  border-bottom-width: var(--line-weight);
  right: calc(50% - var(--line-weight) / 2);
}

.item:nth-child(3) .line:nth-child(1)::before {
  left: calc(100% + var(--line-weight) / 2);
}

.item:nth-child(3) .line:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: var(--line-radius) 0 0 0;
  border-left-width: var(--line-weight);
  border-top-width: var(--line-weight);
  top: calc(50% - (var(--line-weight) / 2 + var(--line-dot-size) / 2));
  right: calc(100% - var(--line-weight) / 2);
}

.item:nth-child(3) .line:nth-child(2)::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: calc(var(--line-weight) * -.5);
}


/* Для демо */
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 125px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

.block,
.item,
.line-block {
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <!-- Основная разметка блока -->
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="line-block">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="line-block">
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="line-block">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ----------------------- -->
</div>
```

P.S. Смотреть открыв сниппет на весь экран.